# Why is my wordpress admin form not working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a WordPress plugin to search a "third party" database. (quotes around third party because I'm hosting the database locally, but the tables aren't managed by WordPress). My problem is this:

```
function show_filter_form() {
    $form= '<form method="post" action="admin-post.php" > <input type="text" name="process_db_form">';
    $form .= ' <input type="submit" value="submit"> </form>';
    echo $form;
}

function process_db_form() {
    wp_redirect('/');
    exit;
}

function show_menu_page() {
        echo __DIR__;
        show_filter_form();
}

function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page( 'Schools Database',  'Schools Database', 'read', 'schools_database', 'show_menu_page');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page' );
add_action( 'admin_post_process_db_form', "process_db_form" );
```

This code, according to all the tutorials I've read, is supposed to redirect to something, theoretically the home page of the site and it doesn't. I've tried it with `wp_redirect( admin_url( '/wp-admin/') );` that doesn't work either. What's wrong?

Comment: Any errors showing up? Are you seeing anything like "headers already sent" anywhere?

Comment: No. Nothing. It just stops at wp-post.php and doesn't do anything else